# How to make my discord bot to detect fields, title field and field description of embeds?

Tags: discord.js, bots, embed

There is a bot that randomly spawn an event using embed message and i want my bot to detect that embed and to respond back. The code bellow works to detect title,description of an embed, but i have no idea how to make it to detect title field or field description.

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message && message.embeds) {

    for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
      if (
        message.embeds[i].description && 
        message.embeds[i].description.includes("arena event")) 
      {
        message.channel.send('<@&721372445457645579> JOIN!')
      }
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `MessageEmbed` class you can have the `fields` property -

```js
 message.embeds[i].fields[0].name
 message.embeds[i].fields[0].value
```

Comment: i changed the code as you said 
`client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message && message.embeds) {

    for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
      if (
        message.embeds[i].fields[0].name && 
        message.embeds[i].fields[0].name.includes("arena event")) 
      {
        message.channel.send('<@&721372445457645579> JOIN!')
      }
    }

  }
});`
It works but after some time gives me this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' or undefined

Comment: it means no field is there

Comment: Try this - `client.on('message', (message) => { if (message && message.embeds) { for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) { if ( message.embeds[i].fields.length && message.embeds[i].fields[0].name.includes("arena event")) { message.channel.send('<@&721372445457645579> JOIN!') } } } });`